# NOT IN subquery versus ON != Operation

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have two tables called ny_clean (3454602 entries) and pickup_0_ids_temp_table (2739268 entries) who have both an id CHAR(11) column which is a primary key and has a BTREE index on top of it  ( MySQL 5.7) .

The "id" column in pickup_0_ids_temp_table is a subset of ny_clean and I want to get a result which is ny_clean without the id values from pickup_0_ids_temp_table.

Option 1:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM pickup_0_ids_temp_table as t
JOIN ny_clean as n
ON n.id != t.id;
```

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key               | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t        | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY           | 11      | NULL | 2734512 |   100.00 | Using index                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ny_clean | NULL       | index | NULL          | btree_pk_ny_clean | 11      | NULL | 3445904 |    90.00 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Option 2:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM ny_clean as n
WHERE n.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM pickup_0_ids_temp_table);
```

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table                   | partitions | type            | possible_keys          | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | n                       | NULL       | ALL             | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 3445904 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pickup_0_ids_temp_table | NULL       | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,btree_pickup_0 | PRIMARY | 11      | func |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

I then use one of the options inside this larger query

```
EXPLAIN
INSERT INTO y    
SELECT id, pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude 
FROM x
JOIN 
(OPTION 1 OR 2) as z
ON z.id =  x.id;
```

When I used Option 1 inside the larger query it ran for two days and it was not finished. Option 2 on the other hand did the job in less than 30minutes

My Question: Why is that?
Following the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-materialization.html) I would suspect that it is due to materialization of the subquery but how would I check this ?

And am I interpreting the EXPLAIN Output wrong? Because judging from it I would expect Option 1 to be faster since it uses an index on both tables

Or does it have to do ith the larger query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first explain has `Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) ` which means the records are matched in two nested loops. which is ofcource bad

Comment: `n.id != t.id` might be possible to be rewritten to `n.id < t.id AND n.id > t.id` then the optimizer should pick range scans

Comment: @RaymondNijland first time I heard that as an optimizing trick.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes it should be OR instead tho `n.id < t.id OR n.id > t.id`.. Not sure tho if the rewrite works out of the box without example data..

Comment: "first time I heard that as an optimizing trick" @JuanCarlosOropeza Well it seams modern MySQL versions 5.7+ optimize `!=` already as a range scan it seams. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czMTmRHZxtSAXKdsGSWkrW/2

Comment: As it stood, the title implied something wrong.  So, I changed the title.

Answer (score 4):

Your option 1 doesn't do what you think will do.

If you have two tables

```
      n.id            t.id
      1               1
      2               2 
      3               3
```

`ON n.id != t.id;`

You get:

```
   1,2
   1,3
   2,1
   2,3
   3,1
   3,2
```

That is almost a cartesian product. So 3.4 mill x 2.7 mill ~ 9.18 mill rows

Then you try to do a JOIN and because that materialzed table doesnt have index will take very long time.

Comment: How did I forget to thank you all this time ago for fixing my problem? I probably facepalmed too hard.